# Combining jQuery and CSS Media queries

Tags: jquery, css, media-queries

I'm using this code to trigger stuff on window resize.

**css**

```css
@media only screen and (min-width : 320px) and (max-width : 768px) {
    .placeholder {
        width:100%;
    }
```

**js**

```css
if ($(window).width() <= 768){ 
$('#middle').hide();
$('.left').removeClass('hidden');

} else {
$('#middle').show();
$('.left').addClass('hidden');
}
});
```

However, these is an inconsistency between the CSS media query at 768 and the jquery window width 768 because they do not appear to trigger at the same time. This is something explained on this great article, http://www.fourfront.us/blog/jquery-window-width-and-media-queries

However, when I try to apply this like

```css
if ($(".placeholder").css("width") === "100%") {
         $('.left').removeClass('hidden');
         $('#middle').hide();
    } else {
        $('#middle').show();
        $('.left').addClass('hidden');
    }
```

This doesn't work. I've tried applying other css values, like a 2px margin, but this also doesn't work. What am I doing wrong? Can anyone help? Many thanks.

Comment: I understand the question, but why not use CSS to do your show/hide?

Comment: What browser are you testing in?

Comment: isherwood- You are absolutely right. I didn't want to bore you with too much code so I didn't put the whole thing. Please see the updated version, I have add and remove classes too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mehdi said, $(".placeholder").css("width") will return you a px value.
To resolve this you can add another style to your class that won't influence in your design
like `border-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);` and use it to your if..

See this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/UaZ65/1/)

Comment: Thanks André! That worked beautifully. I was trying to do that before but for some reason it didn't work. It works now!

Answer (score 1):

even if you set the `width:100%`, *`$(".placeholder").css("width")`* give you width in **px**

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SNH4w/3/)**

```
if ($(".placeholder").css("width") == $(window).width()+"px")//or $(container).width()
```

means **.placeholder** width is 100% if margin=0

Comment: no, sorry. That was a bad choice of div name. Forget about #this, let's call it #blue.

Comment: I don't think so because that would be targeting `window`.